# too few arguments to function ‘peachy’

Tags: c

I've been trying to practice working with arguments and functions but I keep getting a "too few arguments error" on this basic attempt. Can anyone point out to me what I need to do in order to get this to compile?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int peachy(char* str, int a, int b)
{
    str = "g";
    a = 7;
    b = 6;
    printf("Character: %s\n", str);
    printf("First Integer: %d\n", a);
    printf("Second Integer: %d\n", b);

}


int main(void)
{
    peachy();

}
```

Comment: Q:  Can anyone point out to me what I need to do in order to get this to compile?   A: Uh, pass "str", "a" and "b" as arguments to peachy()?  You might also want to return a value from peachy(), or change the signature to "void"...

Comment: Arguments are expected to be provided *by the caller*, not hardcoded into the function itself. That's the whole point of them being... well... *arguments*, and not regular function-local variables.

Comment: @paulsm4 Alternatively remove the function params and just leave it void, since youre not using them now anyways.

Comment: It's cool man, everything's `peachy();`

Comment: sometimes we have to remember that for beginners some things that are 'obvious' are in fact not 'obvious'. When I learned fortran I could not understand how you could write complex programs, I though it all had to fit on one line. Then somebody said , "you can have as many lines as you need" - aha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void peachy(char* str, int a, int b)
{
    printf("Character: %s\n", str);
    printf("First Integer: %d\n", a);
    printf("Second Integer: %d\n", b);

}


int main(void)
{
    peachy("g", 7, 6);
    peachy("foo", 42, 43); //just to show the use of function args    
}
```